# How to ls using the long format (-l) while still following directory symlinks?

Tags: ls, symlink

I've noticed that `ls -l` doesn't only change the formatting of the output, but also how directory symlinks are handled:

```
> ls /rmn
biweekly.sh  daily.sh  logs ...

> ls -l /rmn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb 11  2011 /rmn -> /root/maintenance/
```

I'd like to get a detailed listing of what's in `/rmn`, not information about the `/rmn` symlink.

One work-around I can think of is to create a shell function that does something like this:

```
cd /rmn
ls -l
cd -
```

But that seems too hacky, especially since it messes up the next use of `cd -`. Is there a better way?

(I'm on CentOS 2.6.9)

Comment: I also noticed that and went googling to see if someone also noticed. That is how I came here. :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

See if your ls has the options:

```
 -H, --dereference-command-line
     follow symbolic links listed on the command line 
 --dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir
     follow each command line symbolic link that points to a directory
```

If those don't help, you can make your macro work without messing up `cd -` by doing:

```
(cd /rmn ; ls -l)
```

which runs in a subshell.

Comment: It does have `-H`, and that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I really wish that `--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir` had a short form.

Answer (score 28):

I don't quite get why the thinking about this simple problem has to be so complex - but perhaps I just got the question the wrong way. Anyways: when I needed a similar functionality, I used:

```
ls -lL
```

That did the trick in my case.
From the `ls` man page:

```
-L, --dereference
     when showing file information for a symbolic link, 
     show  information  for  the file the link references
     rather than for the link itself
```

For instance, I've made me a `/media/stick` shortcut to access the data on my USB stick. `ls -l /media/stick` will show the actual link, while `ls -lL /media/stick` will show the *contents* on the USB stick.

After some deeper research about the difference between the inner workings of `-H` and `-L`, I finally came across an excellent article about this matter on [Shallow Thoughts](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/cmdline/ls-showing-symlinks-and-zsh-stripping-slashes.html) blog (even featuring some neat shell script tricks for your pleasure!)

This points out the **subtle differences** between the two options (way better than the original manual does!) as follows:

- `-H` -- only dereference those links explicitly mentioned on the command line
- `-L` -- dereference links even if they are *not* mentioned on the command line

(When these two are used with *simple* everyday tasks, there ought to be no difference in the output in general.)

Besides: Should you prefer to remember the long form (*`--option`*), it's most probably less cumbersome to memorize `--dereference` than the excessively long monster of `--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir`.

Comment: None of these options work in my shell ... how would I typically recover this functionality?

Answer (score 8):

```
ls -l /rmn/
```

would do it or

```
ls -l /rmn/.
```

However, the behavior should not be different with and without `-l`. Have you got an alias for `ls`?

Comment: `ls` flags are crazy.  `-l` makes `-H` default to off, as does `-F`. See [coreutils - Which files are listed](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Which-files-are-listed.html#Which-files-are-listed).

Comment: @Mikel it appears that you are completely right about that. And yes, that's nuts. (also, I don't have an alias for ls, tried escaping it but the results are the same)

Comment: Indeed it's even  specified by POSIX. I was the one with an `ls='ls -F'` alias actually.